# Reading char from file in c++

Tags: c++

I have created a file hangman_word_collection.txt and stored all the content of file into the string line.

Now I want to use the line string in my program but `line[0]` is not having any value into it or I don't know if it have something in it.

I am new to this please help.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string line;

ifstream myfile ("hangman_word_collection.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (myfile.good()) {
        getline (myfile,line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
for(int i=0; i <= 79; i++) {
    cout << "\n" << i;
    cout << ":" << line[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
actingraringbackupcampusdacoiteasilyfabricgardenhackediceboxprimeralwaysupload.


0:
1:c
2:t
3:i
4:n
5:g
6:r
7:a
8:r
9:i
10:n
11:g
12:b
13:a
14:c
15:k
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: If you change the final `cout` line to `cout<<":"<< (int) (line[i]);` does it print a number value? and if so, what number is it?

Comment: it is printing printing some numbers
Hello World!
actingraringbackupcampusdacoiteasilyfabricgardenhackediceboxprimeralwaysupload.


0:0
1:99
2:116
3:105
4:110
5:103
6:114
7:97
8:114
9:105
10:110
11:103
12:98
13:97
14:99
15:107Press <RETURN> to close this window...

Comment: Is there some purpose to the while loop in the first place. you only want the *last* line in the file?? Look how much space is after your initial output line. at least three returns there, which tells me you have blank lines *after* your data line, therefore clearing your line buffer and hard-terminating it as CashCow describes below.

Comment: not in this thing but i will use for some multiline file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `getline` fails on writing to your target `line` you are assuming it will not modify what is in that string but it is blanking the string, which internally is replacing character 0 with a null character.

The rest is undefined behaviour as you are reading characters off the end of the logical string.

To fix this issue change your code to;

```
string line;

ifstream myfile ("hangman_word_collection.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile.good())
    {
       std::string temp;
       if( getline( myfile, temp ) )
       {
           temp.swap( line );
           cout <<line<<endl;
       }
    }
}
```

Note that it is bad practice to hard-code in magic numbers like 79. If you had put `line.size()` instead you would have seen what size the string actually is, and there would be no undefined behaviour. You can store this in a variable outside the loop if you are worried about performance, although chances are it makes little difference.

Comment: +1 This is totally the problem. No idea what that while-loop is even there for; perhaps future aspirations for a multi-line word list. nice catch.

Comment: I don't know why it is there either. I just applied the minimum fix that would work, that reads the last valid line in the file.

Comment: when i tried same code without using while  and just using            getline(myfile,line);
        cout <<line<<endl;   inside if than it is working properly . why so?

Comment: @CashCow I have 2 texts in my file. But only the second one is read